# Confusion about the expansion of $\mathfrak{u}(n)$ in some arbitrary basis

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $M \in \mathfrak{u}(n)$ be some hermitian matrix, and let $\{t_a\}, a=1,...,n^2$, be some basis for $\mathfrak{u}(n)$. Since $M$ is diagonalizable, we can write $M = UDU^\dagger$, where $D$ is the matrix of eigenvalues of $M$ and $U \in U(n)$ is some unitary matrix that diagonalizes $M$. Now, $D \in \mathfrak{u}(n)$, so we can expand $D = d^ih_i$, where $d^i$ are some expansion coefficients (in fact, $d^i = Tr(Dh^i)$) and $\{h_i\}, i = 1,..., n$, is a subset of $\{t_a\}$ consisting only of Cartan generators (the diagonal generators). The diagonalization is now

$M = d^iUh_iU^\dagger = d^iAd_Uh_i = d^i\Lambda_{ai}(U)t_a$, (1)

where $Ad_Uh_i = Uh_iU^\dagger$ is the adjoint representation acting on Cartan generators and $\Lambda_{ai}$ is the matrix representation of this linear transformation. Now, on the left hand side of equation (1), we have $n^2$ coordinates, $M_{ij}$, and on the right hand side we have $n + n^3$ ones, $(d^i, \Lambda_{ai})$. To be consistent, we must have some constraints that reduces the number of independent components of $\Lambda$ to $n(n-1)$. So, it seems to me that the expansion in the right hand side of (1) will have only $n-1$ generators $t_a$, which is really weird to me, but I cannot find my mistake. What's wrong with those considerations?

Comment: I have just edited to clarify those points.

Comment: Thank you, I will delete my earlier comment. More questions: 1) Shouldn't it be $\sum_1^n d^i h_i$ then, and $M = \sum ...$ ?   --  2) I do not quite understand: When you say the LHS "has $n^2$ coordinates" etc., it seems like now you let $M$ vary. But then the equation becomes invalid, because not all $M$ are simultaneously diagonalisable -- you would have to choose different $U$'s for different $M$'s, right?

Comment: As a general remark, have you tried writing it down explicitly for $n=2$?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Yes, there is a summation over repeated indices, I forgot to mention that. You made some good points, $M$ does vary, but $U$ and $\Lambda$ also vary. And yes, I should try to do some example. But my main concern is that this argument seems ok to me, and it can't be so because $M$ is some general hermitian matrix, so it's expansion in a basis of the algebra should'nt be constrained to involve only some of the generators.

Comment: I find it funny that you believe your argument is correct but notice the result is weird, and ask about it here, but have not written it out in one example. That's the first thing I would do. Actually, already in the case $n=1$ you should see something is off: What would the $n +n^3$ coordinates be that you claim there? In this case the adjoint rep. is just the identity, making $\Lambda_{11}$ being just constant $\equiv 1$, and having no "coordinates" at all. That suggests to look at this part of the argument in general.